# Вывести метабоксы для заполнения пользователем Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Для вукомерса я добавил несколько метабоксов, через плагин Meta Box и нужно вывести их для заполнения пользователю.
 На сайт установлен плагин Docan.
Я в метабоксы вукомерса добавил такие метаполя:
Гарантия,производитель,бренд, ссфлка на сайт компании и т д, вообщем это текстовые инпуты грубо говоря, и через плагин МетаБокс добавил визуальный редактор Раздел Инструкция и Характеристики
 В общем как вывести их на товаре то понятно, вопрос вот в чём:
Мне нужно вывести их на страницу добавления товара, что б пользователь, когда добавлял товары через Docan так же заполнял и эти поля.

Что б вас не запутать:
1) Как вывести эти метаполя пользователю что б он заполнил их при добавлении товара в докане
2) Потом я так понимаю записать это всё в переменную?
3) Как мне тогда вывести эту переменную в карточке товара

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'prefix_register_meta_boxes' );
function prefix_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = 'product_';
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id'         => 'Instruction',
        'title'      => 'Доп.инфо',
        'post_types' => 'product',
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',

        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name'  => 'Инструкция',
                'desc'  => 'Введите инструкцию к товару',
                'id'    => 'instr',
                'type'  => 'wysiwyg',
                'raw'  => false,
                'options' => array(
                  'textarea_rows' => 4,
                  'teeny' => true
                )
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => 'Характеристики',
                'desc'  => 'Введите характеристики товара',
                'id'    => 'har',
                'type'  => 'wysiwyg',
                'raw'  => false,
                'options' => array(
                  'textarea_rows' => 4,
                  'teeny' => true
                )
            )
        )
    );
    return $meta_boxes;
  }
```

Добавление визуального редактора в карточку товара через плагин

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields7' );

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save7' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields7() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // text
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
  array( 
    'id'          => '_text_brand', 
    'label'       => __( 'Бренд', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => '',
    'desc_tip'    => 'true',
    'description' => __( 'Введите название бренда', 'woocommerce' ) 
  )
);

  echo '</div>';

}
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save7( $post_id ){
     // Text Field
  $woocommerce_text_field3 = $_POST['_text_brand'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field3 ) ){
      update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_brand', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field3 ) );
       }
     else{
      update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_brand', '' );
     }
  }
```

А это одно из текстовых полей

Мб пригодится для того что б дать ответ, если нужно ещё какой то код скажите я добавлю.

Answer (score 0):

Жаль что ни кто так и не ответил)
Но я нашёл решение собственной проблемы)
Оставлю тут, может кому то пригодится)

В Докане за добавление нового продукта отвечает файл:
docan-lite/templates/products/new-product-single.php

в нём в самом начале есть такая проверка

```
<?php

global $post;
$from_shortcode = false;

if ( !isset( $post->ID ) && ! isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) ) {
    wp_die( __( 'Доступ запрещен, продукт не найден', 'dokan-lite' ) );
}

if( isset( $post->ID ) && $post->ID && $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $post_title = $post->post_title;
    $post_content = $post->post_content;
    $post_excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
    $post_status = $post->post_status;
    $product        = wc_get_product( $post_id );
}
```

Вообщем в переменную добавляются данные из поста

Сюда я добавил свои переменные, так как в коде который находится в вопросе я привёл пару примеров из своих метаполей, то и ответ буду давать на том же примере

У меня в начале идут два визуальных редактора как метаполя и айди у них "instr" и "har"

```
'id'    => 'instr',
'id'    => 'har',
```

Нужно добавить эти айди в переменную и записать в проверку выше

В итоге получится

```
<?php

global $post;
$from_shortcode = false;

if ( !isset( $post->ID ) && ! isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) ) {
    wp_die( __( 'Доступ запрещен, продукт не найден', 'dokan-lite' ) );
}

if( isset( $post->ID ) && $post->ID && $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $post_title = $post->post_title;
    $post_content = $post->post_content;
    $post_excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
    **$har = $post->har;
    $instr = $post->instr;**
    $post_status = $post->post_status;
    $product        = wc_get_product( $post_id );
}
```

И в нужном месте я вывожу:

```
<div class="dokan-form-group">
   <label for="har" class="form-label"><?php _e( 'Характеристики', 'dokan-lite' ); ?></label>
   <?php wp_editor( $har, 'har', array('editor_height' => 50, 'quicktags' => false, 'media_buttons' => false, 'teeny' => true, 'editor_class' => 'har') ); ?>
</div>
<div class="dokan-form-group">
    <label for="instr" class="form-label"><?php _e( 'Инструкция', 'dokan-lite' ); ?></label>
    <?php wp_editor( $instr, 'instr', array('editor_height' => 50, 'quicktags' => false, 'media_buttons' => false, 'teeny' => true, 'editor_class' => 'instr') ); ?>
```

Обратите внимание на аргументы, 1-й переменная которую я указал в проверке, а второй айди этой переменной

Теперь вариант с инпутом:
Так же само дабавим его в проверку

```
<?php

global $post;
$from_shortcode = false;

if ( !isset( $post->ID ) && ! isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) ) {
    wp_die( __( 'Доступ запрещен, продукт не найден', 'dokan-lite' ) );
}

if( isset( $post->ID ) && $post->ID && $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $post_title = $post->post_title;
    $post_content = $post->post_content;
    $post_excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
    $har = $post->har;
    **$_text_brand = $post->_text_brand;**
    $instr = $post->instr;
    $post_status = $post->post_status;
    $product        = wc_get_product( $post_id );
}
```

Опять же придумываем переменную и указываем айди метаполя
И в нужном месте выводим

```
<div class="dokan-form-group">
    <label for="_text_warranty" class="form-label"><?php _e( 'Бренд', 'dokan-lite' ); ?></label>
    <?php dokan_post_input_box( $post_id, '_text_brand', array( 'placeholder' => __( 'Название бренда', 'dokan-lite' ) ), 'text' ); ?>
</div>
```

Тут уже первым аргументом идёт айди поста(он уже указан Доканом по дефолту), а вторым, айди метаполя.
 В карточке товара теперь появятся данные метаполя (если вы их уже вывели с помощью `get_post_meta()`)
Вот и всё)